# Checkbox colors based on mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Very new to coding and had to build a reservation app over the last few weeks. I am trying to get results back if the seats are already booked and:

1. prevent the seat from being booked again (error message)
2. change the checkbox color to red

I chose to use checkboxes but if you have a beautiful array or table I could use I'm open to suggestions. The seats are supposed to be red if booked, green if booked by current active user, and white if not booked.

Currently the flow is seats.html -> cart.php -> reserve.php (the order is different, I mostly need help with reserve.php and seats.html.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

---

--reserve.php--

```
<?php session_start();
include 'dbh.php';
$seat = $_GET['seat'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];  

//this was supposed to check for seats already booked but I couldn't get it to work :[ 

$checkseat = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE seat = '$_GET[seat]'";
$rs = mysqli_query($connection,$checkseat);
$data = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);

if($data[0] > 1) {
    echo "Seat is already reserved<br/>";
}

else
{
    $newSeat="INSERT INTO reservations (id, seat)
        VALUES ('$id','$seat')";

    if (mysqli_query($connection,$newSeat))
    {
        echo "$seat is booked for user: $id";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: Seat already booked.<br/>";
    }
}
```

---

--seats.html--

```
<?php session_start(); include 'dbh.php'; $seat=$ _GET[ 'seat']; ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Select Seats</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="mycounter2"></div>
        <!--script for timer on page load-->
        <script>
            i = 60;

            function onTimer2() {
                document.getElementById('mycounter2').innerHTML = i;
                i--;

                onclick = function() {
                    i = 60;
                }

                if (i < 0) {
                    alert('Your seat selection has been reset.');
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(onTimer2, 1000);
                }
            }
            window.onload = onTimer2;
        </script> seconds until seats are cleared.
        <br />
        <br />

        <style type="text/css">
            .tg {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                border-color: #999;
            }

            .tg td {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 10px 5px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-break: normal;
                border-color: #999;
                color: #444;
                background-color: #F7FDFA;
            }

            .tg th {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 10px 5px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-break: normal;
                border-color: #999;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #26ADE4;
            }

            .tg .tg-yw4l {
                vertical-align: top
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
                .tg {
                    width: auto !important;
                }
                .tg col {
                    width: auto !important;
                }
                .tg-wrap {
                    overflow-x: auto;
                    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                }
            }
        </style>

        <h1>Reserve Seats</h1>
        <!--script for timer on page load-->
        <script>
            i = 60;

            function onTimer() {
                alert("test");
                document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
                i--;
                if (i < 0) {
                    alert('No activity, seats not held.');
                } else {
                    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
                }
            }
        </script>
<!--the below script prevents users from selecting more than 4 seats--> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit) {
                var checkgroup = checkgroup
                var limit = limit
                for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
                    checkgroup[i].onclick = function() {
                        var checkedcount = 0
                        for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++)
                            checkedcount += (checkgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0
                        if (checkedcount > limit) {
                            alert("You can select a maximum of " + limit + " seats")
                            this.checked = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div class="tg-wrap">
            <table class="tg">
                <form id="reserve" name="reserve" action="cart.php" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">1</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">2</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">3</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">4</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">5</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">6</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">7</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">8</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">9</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">10</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">11</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">12</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">13</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">14</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">15</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">16</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">17</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">18</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">19</th>
                        <th class="tg-yw4l">20</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A1">A1</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A2">A2</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A3">A3</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A4">A4</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A5">A5</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A6">A6</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A7">A7</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A8">A8</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A9">A9</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A10">A10</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A11">A11</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A12">A12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A13">A13</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A14">A14</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A15">A15</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A16">A16</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A17">A17</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A18">A18</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A19">A19</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="A20">A20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B1">B1</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B2">B2</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B3">B3</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B4">B4</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B5">B5</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B6">B6</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B7">B7</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B8">B8</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B9">B9</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B10">B10</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B11">B11</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B12">B12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B13">B13</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B14">B14</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B15">B15</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B16">B16</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B17">B17</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B18">B18</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B19">B19</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="B20">B20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C1">C1</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C2">C2</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C3">C3</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C4">C4</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C5">C5</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C6">C6</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C7">C7</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C8">C8</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C9">C9</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C10">C10</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C11">C11</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C12">C12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C13">C13</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C14">C14</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C15">C15</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C16">C16</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C17">C17</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C18">C18</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C19">C19</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="C20">C20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D1">D1</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D2">D2</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D3">D3</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D4">D4</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D5">D5</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D6">D6</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D7">D7</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D8">D8</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D9">D9</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D10">D10</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D11">D11</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D12">D12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D13">D13</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D14">D14</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D15">D15</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D16">D16</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D17">D17</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D18">D18</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D19">D19</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="D20">D20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E1">E1</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E2">E2</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E3">E3</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E4">E4</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E5">E5</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E6">E6</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E7">E7</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E8">E8</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E9">E9</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E10">E10</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E11">E11</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E12">E12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E13">E13</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E14">E14</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E15">E15</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E16">E16</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E17">E17</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E18">E18</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E19">E19</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" value="E20">E20</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                checkboxlimit(document.forms.reserve["seat[]"], 4)
            </script>

            <!--timer script below resets page after 60 seconds of no clicks--> 
                    <div id="mycounter"></div>
                    <script>
                        i = 60;
                        function onTimer() {
                            $("submit").show(1000);
                            document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
                            i--;
                            if (i < 0) {
                                alert('Your reservation has timed out.');
                            } else {
                                setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <button type="submit" class="button button-block" /><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
                    </button>
                    <?php echo "string"; </body>

</html>
```

---

--cart.php--

```
<?php session_start();
include 'dbh.php';
//seat from previous page selection

$seat = implode(', ', $_POST['seat']);
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body> 
<?php 
echo "Shopping Cart <br /><br /> $id's Seats: $seat <br /><br /> Please confirm within 60 seconds.<br /><br />";
?>
<div id="mycounter"></div>
<!--script for timer on page load--> 
<script>
i = 60;
function onTimer() {
  document.getElementById('mycounter').innerHTML = i;
  i--;
  if (i < 0) {
    alert('Your reservation has timed out.');
    window.history.back();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
  }
}
window.onload = onTimer;
</script>
<br />
<br />

<?php 
echo '<button><a href="reserve.php?seat=' . $seat . '">Confirm</a></button>';?>
<button type="submit" class="button button-block"/><a href="seats.html">Cancel</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What data-type and value is `$data[0]` holding? if it's a boolean value you should have `$data[0] > 0`

Comment: It would hold the results from the table, so an array

Answer (score 1):

`if ($data[0] > 1)` translates to 'if the first row from result array is greater than 1', instead of checking if the first row is greater than 1, check if the query returns more than 0 rows.

```html
<?php

$checkseat = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE seat = '$_GET[seat]'";
$rs = mysqli_query($connection,$checkseat);
// get the row count of the result
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
$data = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);

if ($row_count > 0) {
echo 'Seat is already reserved<br/>';
}

?>
```

As for any other issues with your code you will need to provide more specific questions. If you're not sure what parts aren't working I suggest enabling error reporting and looking at the browsers console for any error messages.

```html
<?php
// this goes at the top of the php page
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```